# Reference to figures with conditional caption (depending on the version)

Tags: cross-referencing, conditionals, comments, versions

I use the versions package for conditional content. However it doesn't work for references with varying captions (i.e., which depend on the version). Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{versions}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\excludeversion{short}
%\includeversion{short}
%\excludeversion{long}
\includeversion{long}

\begin{document}

\begin{short}
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{short}

\begin{long}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{long}

This is a reference to Fig.~\ref{fig:varyingcaption}, which has a varying caption.

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\framebox(100,50){}
\begin{short}
\caption{SHORT caption}
\end{short}
\begin{long}
\caption{LONG caption}
\end{long}
\label{fig:varyingcaption}
\end{figure}

This is a reference to Fig.~\ref{fig:fixcaption}, which has a fix caption.

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\framebox(100,50){}
\caption{Fix caption}
\label{fig:fixcaption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the reference for the first figure is ?? while the reference for the the second figure is 2.

I have also tried to use the comment package instead of the versions package and changed the include/exclude commands above as follows

```
\excludecomment{short}
%\includecomment{short}
%\excludecomment{long}
\includecomment{long}
```

and have similar problem, but now the ?? has been replaced by a space (i.e., no reference to the first figure is given).

Comment: `\begin{long}` is a bad idea, since `\long` has a TeX-internal meaning. However, you have to use the `\label` inside your `long` or `short` environment, not outside, otherwise, it would use the last `\@currentlabel` from another `\refstepcounter` call, which could be anything (or just empty)

Answer (score 1):

To begin with: The package `version` seems to define environments like the name of `\includeversion{foo}` etc, i.e. `\begin{foo}...\end{foo}` will be defined.

This is basically no problem, but the starter command of the environment `foo` is `\foo`, so calling the environment `long` is really bad, since `\long` is a TeX primitive, it should not be redefined!

Now, the label issue:

If you hide the `\caption` inside an environment, the `\@currentlabel` redefined by `\refstepcounter` does not make it's definition outside of the environment. In order to inform `\label` about `\@currentlabel`, you have to use it inside the versions environments.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{versions}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\excludeversion{shortversion}
\includeversion{shortversion}
\excludeversion{longversion}
%\includeversion{longversion}

\begin{document}

\begin{shortversion}
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{shortversion}

\begin{longversion}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{longversion}

This is a reference to Fig.~\ref{fig:varyingcaption}, which has a varying caption.

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\framebox(100,50){}
\begin{shortversion}
\caption{SHORT caption}
\label{fig:varyingcaption}
\end{shortversion}
\begin{longversion}
\caption{LONG caption}
\label{fig:varyingcaption}
\end{longversion}

\end{figure}

This is a reference to Fig.~\ref{fig:fixcaption}, which has a fix caption.

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\framebox(100,50){}
\caption{Fix caption}
\label{fig:fixcaption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```